# Download Tableau view using python

Tags: python, pandas, tableau-api

I am looking for a way to download a view of tableau using python. I'm able to login into tableau online via python and able to see listed workbooks and views.

as user doesn't have permission of workbook so can't able to download a workbook, but view I'm able to just entering in chrome but can't able to find a way using python. also i want to save the view in pandas dataframe.

if there is anyway to do the above, kindly let me know?

```
# coding=utf-8

import tableauserverclient as TSC
import argparse
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()

tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('admin', 'admin', site_id='test')
server = TSC.Server('https://10az.online.tableau.com')
server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth)
# print(server.projects.get())
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get()
    print("\nThere are {} workbooks on site: ".format(pagination_item.total_available))
    print([workbook.name for workbook in all_workbooks])

    if all_workbooks:
        sample_workbook = all_workbooks[3]
        server.workbooks.populate_views(sample_workbook)
        print("\nName of views in {}: ".format(sample_workbook.name))
        print([view.name for view in sample_workbook.views])
        print([view.id for view in sample_workbook.views])

        server.workbooks.populate_connections(sample_workbook)
        print("\nConnections for {}: ".format(sample_workbook.name))
        print(["{0}({1})".format(connection.id, connection.datasource_name)
               for connection in sample_workbook.connections])

        view_id = 'ddd'
        server_url = 'https://10az.online.tableau.com'
        src_url = "https://10az.online.tableau.com/#/site/abc/views/test/AccountAdvertisersList.csv" \
                  .format(server_url, server.version, server.site_id, view_id)

        # path = server.workbooks.download(sample_workbook.id)
```

Comment: Do you want to download the image or the data?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore i want to download the data.